# Homebrew instillation failed

Tags: terminal, homebrew

I get this error when trying to install homebrew:

```
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/local/share/zsh: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions: Operation not permitted
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod 755 /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

(macos 10.15.7)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

Also, `brew doctor` would help you with your `brew` usage.